# How to add leading zeros where applicable?

Tags: regex, vbscript

If, in a string, there are valid numbers without a leading zero, like ".5", "+.5", or "-.5", how to use RegExp to match such a pattern and then add a leading zero?

Say,

```
s=".5x-.3/+.74x1.2"
```

I want it to be

```
0.5x-0.3/+0.74x1.2
```

and use

```
(?!\d)([+-]?)(?!\d)(\.\d+)
```

as Pattern and `$10$2` as Replacement, but why doesn't it deliver the right things?

PS: I am using VBScript RegExp engine in Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Replace `(?<!\d)\.(?=\d)` with `0.`, assuming your regex flavor supports negative look-behind.</del>

`(?<!\d)` is *not preceded by a digit* (different from `\D` wich would be *preceded by a character that is not a digit* and wouldn't match if the string begins with `.5`), non-consuming (negative look-behind).

`\.` is the dot (duh), consuming.

`(?=\d)` means that the dot must be *followed by a digit*, non-consuming (positive look-ahead).

The only consumed character is the dot, so you only have to replace it with `0.`.

---

**Edit**: Since VBScript doesn't support look-behinds, you can use the slightly more complicated replacement of `(\D|^)\.(?=\d)` with `$10.` (assuming the VBScript flavor doesn't try to get the 10th group, wich JavaScript doesn't seem to do). The `(\D|^)\.` part will match a dot preceded by either the start of the string or any non-digit character. This previous character is consumed, so you have to put it back, hence the `$1`.

Comment: This won't work - VBScript is an ECMAScript dialect, and therefore lookbehind assertions are not available, as I've detailed in my answer.

Comment: thank you all for let me know _lookaround_ better now! @streetpc's code `(\D|^)\.(?=\d)` works. VBScript flavor doesn't support _lookbehind_. Have to use this way to work around.

Answer (score 1):

```
\B\.
```

matches a dot only if it's not preceded by a digit (or letter), which should work for your requirements. Replace that with `0.`

Why doesn't your regex work? Well, it says

```
(?!\d)  # Make sure the next letter isn't a digit
([+-]?) # Try to match a sign (which never is a digit, so why the lookahead?)
(?!\d)  # Make sure the next letter isn't a digit (again)
(\.\d+) # Match a dot and digits (the dot also isn't a digit, so again
        # the lookahead is not necessary)
```

So, you could drop the first lookahead completely, and the second *lookahead* would have to be a *lookbehind* to do what you want it to do (namely asserting that the character *before*  the dot isn't a digit), but ECMAScript doesn't know lookbehinds, so we have to make do with word boundary anchors.

Comment: Isn't `\D` "anything but a digit"?

Comment: @Simon, it is `\B` "not a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)", the negation of `\b` and not `\D`

Comment: Does this fail on `.5x.5`, because the `.` is preceded by a letter? Seems `x` is being used here for multiplication.